# No 'Actions' panel in Django Admin

Tags: django

Following the directions here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/actions/
but there is no 'Action' panel to select anything. Also my 'Select All' checkbox doesn't work, may or may not be related.

What should I look at to troubleshoot?
[image]

Comment: I assume you have tried to click on the "Action:" drop-down menu and didn't find your custom Action. Can you share your admin.py changes?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your custom templates by renaming the template folder or outcommenting the path in settings.py